# Optimization of animation for large quantity of objects

Tags: unity, animation, optimization

I have run into a problem where I need to animate plenty of circles just scaling up and down.

When I use animator, it needs 16ms per frame for 10000 circles. It drops fps significantly from 1000 to 30.

If I use scripts to scale the object, the result would be probably the same or worse, 10000 coroutines changing `localScale`.

What is the approach to this kind of problem? In agar io for example, they have done this without decreasing fps significantly, the game runs in a browser.

What are the optimizations that can be made?

Use of shaders? Chunks of objects animating as group at the same frame in animation?

Comment: You might be able to use shaders for this, but in order to be sure you need to tell us what rule you're using to decide which circles should be what size, and when. We'll need to translate that rule into shader code, if it relies only on data the shader knows about, like position & time.

Comment: @DMGregory Circles have just 2 states that change in animation from Vector3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2) to Vector3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3) in localScale. So I guess time in the shader would do it. Maybe Lerp(0.2, 0.3, sin(time)). I just need to be sure if that is fast enough approach before implementing it because I'm not a pro with shaders, though, it looks simple it might take some time.

Answer (score 1):

The key to this problem is not rendering and animating something, that's not on the screen.

If the scaling happens based on a formula, then you could even stop changin their animation states, and only focus on the visible stuff.

Agario has an additional advantage, the server doesn't habe to render anything and the client doesn't have to calculate anything

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though Unity doesn't render things that aren't visible by default, it does animate them but every frame or even some other time in coroutine checking if the object is in a visible area would make it even worse. Then the areas should be divided but then it takes time to implement that and in addition, you have to correct the number of visible areas or recalculating them depending on camera FOV.

Comment: @CandidMoon Checking whether something's visible or not is literally 12 operations, animating an object takes more time

Comment: @CandidMoon Unity already does visibility calculations for everything by itself. And it exposes that in form of an Unity event. Use [`OnWillRenderObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnWillRenderObject.html) to implement code you only want to run on frames where the object is on-screen.

Comment: @Philipp I am not sure, I guess the `OnWillRenderObject` is a `message`. And hopefully it doesn't work via reflection. I bet they are not making calculations if this event isn't written in Behaviour script. Thus standard calculations will be made if it's added. Unless they really do calculate them anyway like in 3D when only objects that are visible are rendered, though, I guess there is no occlusion culling for 2D, but I haven't tried that. It would be nice if it was possible to have it in 2D and get the objects that are not being culled.

Answer (score 1):

When you use classic Unity game objects, then Unity is far better at processing a few complex game objects than a large number of simple game objects.

When your game needs the latter, then the new [Unity Entity-Component-System architecture](https://unity3d.com/unity/features/job-system-ECS) could help you. It requires to restructure your whole software architecture in ways which are too complex to adequately describe them in just one answer. But if you do it, then Unity will be able to process your game objects in a much more efficient way.

Comment: That might work. The question was created before there was ECS in Unity or before it was popular, I don't even know what to do with it, without any tests it seems that it would be inappropriate to mark some question as solution. It's both broad and narrow question. Because a lot of solutions could be valid, but also there is a very good ones that come basically to low use of processing, and it's not architectural with different advantages. The answer that will give the most performance is the most correct. As this is Unity, it's probably the best to use ECS with validation for visibility.

Comment: I guess I will leave it like that and wait for the question that has all adequate optimizations. Or just wait for people to vote and choose the most voted answer, though, the question is not that popular.